# laravel eloquent: whereDate not found record included into the period

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a table with two date fields:

- reservation_begin
- booking_end

I want to know the reservations that occupy me from August 25th to August 31st.

In the select query I have:

```
Booking::select ('id', ''name', reservation_begin', 'reservation_end')
                        ->whereDate('reservation_begin', '>=', $startDate)
                        ->whereDate('reservation_end', '<=', $endDate)
                        ->get();
```

I will NOT find the record in the database if:
$startDate = '2021-08-25';
$endDate = '2021-09-01'
(from 25 August to 1 September).

I want to have reservations that include the period from August 25 to August 31, and the reservation that goes from August 25 to September 1 still includes that period, how can I get it out?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug but there is a space between ```> = ``` in the first whereDate. Try removing that and try

Comment: Do you also want any overlapping reservations? These will `occupy` any of the days, not just all.  If so, try:
                        `->whereDate('reservation_begin', '<=', $endDate)`
                        `->whereDate('reservation_end', '>=', $startDate)`

Comment: @MarvinCollins it was a typo, there is no space in the original code

Comment: @JonArmstrong : the solution is not working correctly. I would like to select the period, for example: August 25 to August 31 and I want to have ALL the records that include those dates, example:
from 25 to 31
from 23 to 31
from 23 January to 30 September
from 31 August to 2 September
etc

all those who "cross" from 25 to 31 August

Comment: Please check my SQL examples (in an answer).  I show both your logic (first) and then a couple of solutions (2nd and 3rd).  These do provide the overlap cases, which is what I think you are requesting.

Comment: Did you want only those that completely cover ALL of your argument dates, and not just overlap any of the dates?  I can add SQL that returns only reservations that completely cover the argument range, if that's what you want.

Comment: I've updated the test case slightly to show your SQL at the top, in two slightly different forms (one with a LEFT JOIN).  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7fc96ef97de4f3f8b713c91c1138451

Comment: Please show your test case, with table definition and data.  Maybe you have a problem not shown in the above detail.

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like you want any overlap cases.  Review the results in the answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a test case with direct SQL, just to show the various logic cases and results.  This can help determine the laravel/eloquent logic to use:

[Working SQL test case (*updated*)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7fc96ef97de4f3f8b713c91c1138451)

A table with some data (using MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
    booking_id         int   primary key auto_increment
  , reservation_begin  date
  , reservation_end    date
);

INSERT INTO booking (reservation_begin, reservation_end) VALUES
    (current_date, current_date + 3)
  , ('2021-08-25', '2021-09-01')
  , ('2021-08-21', '2021-08-24')
  , ('2021-08-23', '2021-08-25')
  , ('2021-09-01', '2021-09-04')
  , ('2021-09-02', '2021-09-07')
;
```

Your logic and result:

```
WITH args (xstart, xend) AS (SELECT '2021-08-25', '2021-09-01')
SELECT t1.*, args.*
  FROM booking AS t1
  JOIN args
    ON t1.reservation_end   <= args.xend 
   AND t1.reservation_begin >= args.xstart 
;
```

[image]

Include overlap cases (return just the matches) and result:

```
WITH args (xstart, xend) AS (SELECT '2021-08-25', '2021-09-01')
SELECT t1.*, args.*
  FROM booking AS t1
  JOIN args
    ON args.xstart <= t1.reservation_end
   AND args.xend   >= t1.reservation_begin
;
```

[image]

Include overlap cases (return the matches, plus null for the non-matches), plus results:

```
WITH args (xstart, xend) AS (SELECT '2021-08-25', '2021-09-01')
SELECT t1.*, args.*
  FROM      booking AS t1
  LEFT JOIN args
    ON args.xstart <= t1.reservation_end
   AND args.xend   >= t1.reservation_begin
;
```

[image]